# Update a row in one table and also creating a new row in another table to satisfy a foreign key relationship

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that updates a type of Star. The database table, starValList, has a foreign key for a table called galaxyValList.  That key is galaxyID.

So I need to create a new galaxyID value if it is null or empty GUID.

So I try this:

```
IF(@galaxyID IS NULL OR @galaxyID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @galaxyID=NEWID()
    END

UPDATE starValList SET 
    [starIRR]= @starIRR,
    [starDesc] = @starDesc,
    [starType] = @starType,
    [galaxyID]=@galaxyID
WHERE [starID] = @starID;
```

And it works for the starValList table!

But I think it fails too because of this error:

```
The UPDATE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_starValList_galaxyValList". The conflict occurred in database "Astro105", table "dbo.galaxyValList", column 'galaxyID'.
```

It fails because there may not yet be an entry for that particular galaxy in galaxyValList table.

But I still need the row in galaxyValList because it can be used later.

How can I fix my stored procedure so that it doesn't generate this error?

Thanks!

Comment: By getting the correct value from your table `dbo.galaxyValList`. Using `NEWID` for the value of `galaxyID` in the table `starValList` has effectively a 100% chance of generating a value that does not exist in `galaxyValList`

Comment: Side note, SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for over a year, and you should be looking at upgrade paths as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `if exists` to check if the value exists on the table. If it does then do an update. If it doesn't then have some other logic to maybe create it or whatever your requirements may be so the value can then be used in an update. Basic example below:

```
IF(@galaxyID IS NULL OR @galaxyID = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
    BEGIN
        SELECT @galaxyID=NEWID()
    END

if not exists ( select top 1 1 from galaxyTable where galaxyId = @galaxyId)
begin 
    -- the @galaxyId doesnt exist, create it so you can use the value in an update later
    insert into galaxyTable ( galaxyId ) select @galaxyId

end

UPDATE starValList SET 
    [starIRR]= @starIRR,
    [starDesc] = @starDesc,
    [starType] = @starType,
    [galaxyID]=@galaxyID
WHERE [starID] = @starID;
```